# How to prevent our site from visitor access via domain masking or url masking

Tags: javascript, domain-masking

Example real site `http://stackoverflow.com/`

[**URL Masking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Masking) `http://masking.com/stackoverflow`

**Question**

How to switch the URL masking `http://masking.com/stackoverflow` to original URL `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Let me know how can be done in PHP or JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Masking site urls are done with frames. All you need to do is add a frame-breaking script.

Just add this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
parent.location.href = self.document.location
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not always true, I recently am facing where it's not through iframe. Please check

Answer (score 0):

A rogue technique of domain masking I've encountered is where multiple domains will intentionally configure their DNS settings to point to my server, so that it appears they are hosting my website as well.

Originally I thought it was done via an iframe or other method until my hosting company confirmed the real reason (and the only reason they knew is because the malicious domains were also purchased via them so they could see its settings).

To fix this, you should configure your web server to deny all requests that don't originate from your domain.

In Apache 2.4, this mean modifying the VirtualHost settings in your Apache site .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName youractualdomain.com
ServerAlias www.youractualdomain.com
<Location />
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

This will allow requests from your domain - both its www and non-www formats.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dummy
<Location />
    Require all denied
</Location>
```

This will block all other requests and serve a HTTP 403 Forbidden response. Note that Apache will no longer serve even when using your server's direct IP address.